# If $f$ is a uniformly continous function, then $|f(x)|\leq a|x|+b$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f$ is a uniformly continous function. Prove that there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x$:
$$|f(x)|\leq a|x|+b$$

I proved it for a Lipschitz function with constant $k$ and taking $y=0$:

$$|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|\leq k$$
$$|f(x)|-|f(0)|\leq|f(x)-f(0)\leq k|x|$$
$$|f(x)|\leq k|x|+|f(0)|$$

Therefore, for a Lipschitz function, this follows taking $a = k,b=|f(0)|$, but I just don't find how to get this for a general value using only the definition of uniformly continous function.

Comment: I think this is very easy from the definition of uniformly continuous function. Please check the definition again.

Comment: @suzuhirose I would've take $y = 0, \epsilon = |x|$, but that doesn't seem right, given that |x| is not a fixed value.

Comment: you didn't check the definition, did you?

Comment: I have for definition that given $\epsilon > 0$, exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all x,y, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $

Comment: From the mere definition I don't find anything I could directly use

Comment: Uniformly continous *where*? The whole $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @martinblasperezpinilla yes, in all \mathbb{R}

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

$f(x)$ uniformly continuous

$\Rightarrow\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}:|x_1-x_2|\leq\delta,|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$, then fix $\epsilon=1$.

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, such that $\frac{|x|}{\delta}\leq k<\frac{|x|}{\delta}+1$, then $\frac{|x|}{k}\leq\delta$.

Note that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k[f(\frac{i}{k}x)-f(\frac{i-1}{k}x)]+f(0)$, so $$|f(x)|\leq\sum_{i=1}^k|f(\frac{i}{k}x)-f(\frac{i-1}{k}x)|+|f(0)|<k+|f(0)|<\frac{1}{\delta}|x|+1+|f(0)|$$
Set $a=\frac{1}{\delta},b=1+|f(0)|$.

Comment: How do you get that $|f(x)|$ is less than that sum? Also, is choosing $a=\frac{1}{\delta }$ plausible? Given that that shouldn't be a fixed value.

Comment: @Rono: Note that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k[f(\frac{i}{k}x)-f(\frac{i-1}{k}x)]+f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Pick any $\epsilon>0$. Then pick $\delta>0$ according to the definition of unifom continuity. Then what can you say by induction about $f(\pm k\frac\delta2)-f(0)$ with $k\in\mathbb N$? What about the values inbetween?